# How to keep integrity of profiles in dual boot Windows / Linux when updating Firefox and Thunderbird?

Tags: firefox, multi-boot, thunderbird, user-profiles, sharing

I'm sharing my Thunderbird and Firefox profiles between Windows 10 (as portable app) and Ubuntu 16 (dual boot).

I install all recommended updates.

This worked for quite some time, until the version difference between the Ubuntu respository and the portableapps.com version led to bugs:

- Ubuntu Firefox can't find or open its password safe and can't store passwords.
- Same for Ubuntu Thunderbird.
- Windows Firefox always needs to reinstall some plugins.
- Windows Thunderbird forgets that the 'Calendar' tab was opened before.

My guess is that these bugs are a result of accessing the same profile with different versions of Thunderbird and Firefox.

Some boilerplate to avoid discussions:

- I know that Mozilla doesn't support sharing of profiles.
- I use POP3 for some email accounts. I know this is an outdated method.
- I don't use Firefox Sync. That's my personal choice.
- I could wait and periodically check the different repositories and update when both versions are in sync, or manually install specific versions, but I don't.
- I'm frequently (about once a day) switching between both operating systems.

I found:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/370581/what-is-the-right-way-to-share-a-thunderbird-profile-between-ubuntu-and-windows
- [Windows and Linux using same Firefox profile](https://superuser.com/questions/1258469/windows-and-linux-using-same-firefox-profile/1432343#1432343)
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sharing_a_profile_between_Windows_and_Linux
- and some blog and forum posts.

One of the versions will periodically (at least for some time) have a lower version than the other OS's version.

I'm afraid that with each update I risk permanently damaging my profile (when accessing it with the older version).

How can I share profiles and keep their integrity?

---

One option would be to put Firefox and Thunderbird into a virtual machine (thus increasing the operating system count to three...) and run that VM from Windows and Linux on startup.

Advantage: Sandboxing

Disadvantages: Extra effort for updating, difficult file exchange, worse system ressource management

Comment: You cite a bunch of things that describe what does and doesn't work and why, and threads that describe solutions and workarounds that people have come up with, and the extent to which they work.  What are you asking here that doesn't duplicate the other threads or is not already exhaustively covered?  It seems like this question is asking, "I know there are design restrictions and limitations, but conjure me some magic that will let me do it anyway."

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for your feedback. I'm asking because I'm not sure if I just can't see the obvious solution or if there actually isn't one.

Comment: You are aware that sharing profiles across OS is not supported?

Comment: It may be possible with batch and shell scripting. Are you allowed to run scripts in that machine?

Comment: Yes, I own that machine and have all privileges.

Comment: I thought about using a 'shared' VM, see the edit to my question. I don't consider that to be a good solution.

Comment: One solution would be an updater which (1) updates only to versions *now* available on both OSes and (2) can update the then older Firefox / Thunderbird version without first starting it (with the chance of destroying the newer profile or not being able to read it).